# add olark chat window to arbitrary url with chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to make a chrome extension that includes adding an olark window to any webpage on click of the browser action button. olark customer support wasn't sure if this was possible but thought it might be. is there any reason why this wouldn't work?

I've been working on it using the 
document.body.appendChild(script); method to add the olark snippet, is this a reasonable approach?

Comment: Yes, you could use the `"document.body.appendChild(script)"` in `myscript.js` and register it in the extension manifest using the content_scripts field: `"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"],...`. See the reference on the link: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: thanks! I've been using using the <all_urls> tag, do the tags you've listed above have advantages over that?

Comment: `"<all_urls>"` :- matches any URL that starts with a permitted scheme (http, https, file, ftp, or chrome-extension)

`"http://*/*"` :- Matches any URL that uses the http scheme

`"https://*/*"` :- Matches any URL that uses the https scheme